Github Chromium Source Build using Xcode not signing correctly
I am trying to build the Chromium source for ios from github.
I followed the instructions for building chromium "chrome" target in xcode.
I have tried both automatic provisioning and manual with a provisioning profile I created on apple's website. I am not perfect, but have built enough ios apps to be very familiar with that process.
I have changed the chromium bundle id to be my own so I can directly control it and the profiles.
I get a successful build in xcode, but when I try to debug the app on my iphone 8 I get the following error when it tries to install on the device:
Showing Recent Messages
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ohBUtA/extracted/Chromium.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

Does anyone know why my signing would not be working? It doesn't seem to use the normal signing scripts and uses something called ninja build scripts.

Ninja is a build system. I don't do Chromium on iOS but on Windows, you will have to use signtool to digitally sign the binary files of Chromium. There's codesign on macOS. You will most likely have to manually sign those binary files

FYI, you can use codesign -dv --verbose path/to/yourapp.app to verify the signature

Thank you for the codesign command line to use. I think I found the issue. This line is in the output: Identifier=org.chromium.ost.chrome.ios.dev. I changed it to and signed it using my own bundle ID. I will have to track down where this is set because I set my own in the info.plist

I changed the way I was setting the bundle id so that it uses the chromium method of a prefix. I then created a new signing profile with that bundle id and still can't get it to install. I get the same error about not being able to verify the signing profile.

You might want to post this question here in the official Chromium developer group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev Some iOS Chromium devs might be able to assist you.
